# Can you export variables to a text file, as variables not a string

Tags: python, export

Hello my problem is that, i need to find a way to export variables as a text file (or another file type) and then import the variables into python so that I can, use them later on within the program. for example

```
i = 0

while I != 10:
    i = i + 1
    Var1 = input("What is your name")
    Var2 = ("What is your surname")

    with open('filename', 'w') as file_out:
        file_out.write(var1 + "/n")
        file_out.write(var2 + "/n")
        file_out.write("/n")
```

Now if I ran this code it would probably (might have messed up typing it here ;P), it would save the variable1 to the first line, variable 2 to the second and then leaves a line in a newly generated text file, but now i need to reopen the text file within python and then use the the first variables result (for example if someone typed 'john', i need the program to know who john is and what his surname is), similarly when its repeated the program will then write below johns name with someone else's (for example 'ethan'), the program will then write below ethan, along with his surname in the same format.

Thus what I'm asking is if there's anyway to instead export these as variables instead of strings, because if so i could just open the text file and tell my program to use the variables. could someone please tell me if what I suggest is at least possible and if they could how to do so.

Comment: You should store them as json

Comment: Couldn't you just read them in with a while loop, step size 2, since the file will follow the format first name, last name, first name, last name, etc.

Comment: As a side note, according to [Kyrubas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2100534/kyrubas), `Var2 = ("What is your surname")` should probably be `Var2 = input("What is your surname")`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to look at the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Use a dictionary to store multiple variables when using this method. It's a useful container for an indeterminate number variables created on the fly.

```
import pickle

myvardict = {}
i = 0
while i != 10
    i =+ 1
    Var1 = input("What is your name")
    Var2 = input("What is your surname")
    myvardict[i] = [Var1, Var2]

pickle.dump(myvardict,"myoutfile.pic")
```

Then to load you'll just need to call the appropriate method

```
import pickle
myvardict = pickle.load("myoutfile.pic")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pickling your object you could store your data as JSON (especially helpful if you're going to export your data structures to other languages).

```
import json
data = dict(i=1,j=12,hello=world)
with open('data.json','w') as json_file:
   json.dump(data)
```

and then you can load it in using:

```
 import json
 data = None
 with open('data.json') as json_file:
     data = json.load(json_file)
```